Should I use raw score or z-score for CFA?
I am running confirmatory factor analyses and my variables have different scales. I wonder whether I should use raw score and report factor loadings of std.all column OR use z-score to run CFA.

What is the goal of your factor analysis? If it is to generate scores or assess fit, then it doesn't matter what scale your indicators are on.

@Noah  Thank you for your reply! I have multiple measures indicating different latent factors and my goal is to compare 2factor correlated model, 4factor correlated model, bifactor model, and second order model and to identify the model having the best model fit.
